# Shell: Undefined behavior of `for`

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a script that looks like this :

`test.sh`

```
!/bin/bash                                                                  
for i in {0..10}                                                          
  do                                                                         
    echo "Welcome $i times"
  done
```

If I run it like `sh test.sh` I get `Welcome {0..10} times` only once

However if I run it as `bash test.sh` I get :

```
Welcome 0 times
Welcome 1 times
 .... and so on
```

Also if I run the same script on a redhat terminal . I get an error :

```
root@UPLC-PPM-DEV-01 TEST]# sh test.sh 
'est.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `do
'est.sh: line 3: `  do
```

What is wrong here ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `for`.

The `{0..10}` syntax is only supported by bash.

In plain sh you can use

```
seq 0 10
```

(if your platform supports it), or

```
i=`expr $i + 1`
```

to create a counter and use `while`.

Comment: `{x..y}` is not only supported by `bash`.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth: ??. it's not supported by `sh`.

Comment: No, but other shells aside from `bash` and your statement might lead some readers to believe that only `bash` supports that syntax. But I guess you just meant in comparison with `sh` ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Decide which shell you want to use, `bash` or `sh`.  `bash` has many syntax extensions, and you show one of them.

Now, you might do: `ls -l /bin/sh` and find:

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 4 Apr 16 11:12 /bin/sh -> bash
```

but don't be fooled into thinking that you can interchange `sh` and `bash`.  The program uses a common trick of checking the name it was called by (in C, `argv[0]`).  If the program is called by the name `sh` then it switches off all the extensions.  To quote the `man` page:

"*If  bash  is  invoked  with  the name sh, it tries to mimic the startup behavior of historical versions of sh as  closely  as  possible,  while conforming  to the POSIX standard as well.*"